# Scala match not working

Tags: scala

Given the following code:

```
    val future = read(1234)  // <-- returns Option[MyClass]
    future.map { mc =>
      println(mc)  // <-- this is printed
      mc match {
        case Some(mc2) => println("class was matched")
        case None  => println("class is None")
        case _ => println("something else")
      }
    }
```

It prints `Some(MyClass(111,222,...`, but it doesn't print anything else, especially it doesn't print `class was matched` even though the Option is Some. Why could this happen?

Comment: There's not enough information here. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the behavior.

Comment: @Silvio I tried to do my best, the application is complex and difficult to extract a simple case. Can you think of at least one reason this may not work?

Comment: I don't know where `read` is implemented. If `read` reads user input, I don't know what value you provided. I also don't know what `MyClass` looks like or acts like at all.

Comment: what does this print? `println(mc)`

Comment: @OptimusPrime it prints `Some(MyClass(111,222,MyClass2(333,444,AAA)))`

Comment: need to know what `read` returns.

Comment: `read` returns `Future[Option[MyClass]]]`

Comment: Try calling `System.out.flush` after your `match` statement. Does it help?

Comment: What does it print when you explicitly evaluate the future? Like this:


for {
 _ <- future.map { mc =>
      println(mc)  // <-- this is printed
      mc match {
        case Some(mc2) => println("class was matched")
        case None  => println("class is None")
        case _ => println("something else")
      }
    }
} yield ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `val` `future` returns an `Option[Foo]`, so the pattern matching would have to match on the value from `Foo`:

```
case class Foo(x: Int)

val future = Option(Foo(42))

future.map { 
  case _: Foo => println("the class is Foo")
  case _: Option[Foo]  => println("option")
}

// class was matched
```

This will print `class was matched`. Note that the compiler will complain about the *fruitless* type test on `Option` because we are matching over something of type `Foo`. But we can use the variable pattern on `Foo.x`

```
future.map {
  case Foo(32) => "nope"
  case Foo(42) => "yep"
  case _ => "something else"
}
Some("yep")
```

If `future` as the name implies has type `Future[Option[Foo]]`, then the matching is right and it should print the right value

```
val future2 = Future {
  Option(Foo(42))
}

future2.map {
  case Some(_) => println("some")
  case None => println("none")
  case _ => println("wat")
}

// some
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `andThen` instead of `map`.

```
val future = read(1234)  // <-- returns Option[MyClass]
future.andThen { mc =>
  println(mc)  // <-- this is printed
  mc match {
    case Some(mc2) => println("class was matched")
    case None  => println("class is None")
    case _ => println("something else")
  }
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly `andThen` have `Try[T]` as an input parameter, so this code won't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check `onFailure`. Usually when something standard and clear does not work, it means that something wrong happened before.

Comment: Not true in this case, I'm in the same situation myself, onFailure doesn't invoke. Wouldn't that, invoking `onComplete()` when it shouldn't, be an even worse problem? :D